# If we restrict the Heaviside step function to $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\},$ does it suddenly become continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

The [Heaviside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) is discontinuous, despite that its continuous at every point except $0$.

Supposing we restricted it to $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\},$ does it suddenly become continuous?

I think 'yes,' but it seems a bit counterintuitive. I just want someone to confirm that I'm not fooling myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep! Continuous at every point in the domain means continuous! Think of $\mathbb{R} \setminus 0$ as being two completely separate chunks of space. You probably wouldn't have a problem with the function that's zero on $[0,1]$ and one on $[3,4]$ being continuous. Something similar happens here.

Comment: Thanks. It seemed like a surprising conclusion at the time, but in retrospect it makes sense.